# FileWriter and BufferedWriter not writing to file

Tags: java, file-io

I am having issues with the FileWriter and BufferedWriter classes. After declaring, initializing, and calling their write methods the files created have no contents. I have run debug mode and seen that the toString function is working perfectly and is returning a valid String. What am I missing?

```
public String toString(){
    String accountInfo = "";

    //creates a String of the account info according to an easily parsed
    //format
    for (int counter = 0; counter < accounts.size(); counter++){
        if (counter == 0){
            accountInfo = accounts.get(counter).getInfo();
        } else{
            accountInfo += "\n" + accounts.get(counter).getInfo();
        }
    }
    return accountInfo;
}

public void saveToFile(){
    File customer = new File(  name + ".txt");
    try {
        FileWriter custWriter = new FileWriter(customer);
        BufferedWriter custBuffer = new BufferedWriter(custWriter);
        custBuffer.write(this.toString());

        //commented out when I thought I needed to use a BufferedWriter
        //custWriter.write(this.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the close method on your writers!

One way to get that automatically is to use try-with-resources:

```
try (BufferedWriter custBuffer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter ...)) {
  custBuffer.write(this.toString());
}
```

This will automatically **close** the writer; if you go with your current code; try adding writer.close() in the end.

Comment: That did it. thanks for the help.

Comment: does the FileWriter need a close(); as well? If I am not using the BufferedWriter that is.

Comment: Only That writer that you are writting to needs close.